# router.config doesn't have all app routes

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-router

I need get all app routes for build dynamic menu.
If all my routes using lazy-loading and someone from this route has lazy-loading children? In router.config I didn't find child routes of lazy-load modules.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mr58ld

Check console in this stackblitz.

Comment: Can you provide your code? What do you mean by find? You can't navigate to them?

Comment: i can navigate to them, but i can't get all app registred routes, because router config doesn't have lazy-load module child routes.

Comment: Without your code I can't really help much but here is [article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-router-nested-routes-and-nested-auxiliary-routes-build-a-menu-navigation-system/) that has a full example

Comment: Add Stackblitz.

Comment: I know that router.config doesn't have child route of lazy module, because lazy module not loaded, but how i can get all app routes without all module loading??

Comment: If you need to know all possible routes, your lazy loaded modules cannot themselves have routing.

Comment: doesn't have any hacks?